# Referenced file contain errors in STS

Tags: mysql, maven, spring-boot, jakarta-ee, spring-tool-suite

I setup an environment STS 4,0 and import a project. In Web-INF folder it gives such error:

> Referenced file contains errors (http://www.ibm.com/webservices/xsd/j2ee_web_services_client_1_1.xsd). For more information, 
>    right click on the message in the Problems View and select "Show Details..."`

It gives the error in the first line.

How to get rid of it...
I am frustrated.

I tried to install "/npm run build" but not successful.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
```

Comment: does it work in a vanilla Eclipse 2019-06 JEE package install?

Comment: I am using Spring tool suite 4,0 using J2EE.

Comment: Yes, I understand that you use STS4, but in order to find out whether this is an issue with the JEE tooling of Eclipse that usually deals with these files and produces those validations, I would recommend to try a vanilla Eclipse 2019-06 JEE package download to see if that produces the same issue. If so, I would recommend to remove the spring-tool-suite tag and add an eclipse-wtp one. If the error happens in STS only, then I would file a bug at https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues and attach a sample project that reproduces the issue.